# Distorted bakes

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

I'm baking an AO map (Selected to Active). The result of the bake is distorted on some parts. The model (selected) looks like this:
[image]

The other model (active) looks like this:
[image]

And the result looks like this (the problem is not only at the red arrows, but also on other parts of the bake):

[image]

The same also happens of i bake normal maps.
Normals, UVs, scaling is all OK. I never encountered this problem before and didn't find a solution on the internet.

EDIT: If i apply an Edge Split Modifier with 0% (all edges) and apply it, the bake is no longer distorted. However, i can't use this modifier.

Comment: My guess: some non planar surfaces on the lowpoly. If possible upload your file to have a look.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't upload the .blend (work related).

Comment: OK, never mind. Simply, the bake here is done along the faces normals of the lowpoly. If these normals are not well oriented (non planar surfaces), the bake will be oriented in a non straight way.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks for the answer. You can post it below so i can mark it (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what is happening during the bake:

[image]

Some parts of your lowpoly mesh are not planar. So, as the bake process projects rays along normals, the bake is done "as if" it has several points of view because of these non planar surfaces (so non aligned normals).

As you said in the comment, using an edge split resolve the issue in your case. So, a solution maybe (if possible for you) to temporary add this modifier, bake and remove the modifier.

Comment: Yes, i added the Edge Split Modifier, applied it, baked and then undid the modifier. Thanks for the help.