# Strange Normal Baking

Tags: uv, baking, normal-map

I'm sure this is a tired question on here, but having scrubbed through a few on here I haven't find an answer directly for this issue.

In baking a normal map, the content bakes perfectly fine but it's perspective is skewed.

The first image is the original object, the second is the low poly with baked normal/AO.
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the second picture appears to have baked an orthographic perspective that is NOT perpendicular to the normal of the face, it's as if it's coming from the top left of the frame. I'm wondering HOW this came about, as the Normals *are* perpendicular, the UV isn't skewed and the bake is just done as any other object. What caused this?

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: may be something like that https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76598/distorted-bakes/76603#76603

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of Lemon!

[Distorted bakes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76598/distorted-bakes/76603#76603)

This resolved the issue. I applied an edge split as per the post, but am still unable to really understand WHY that worked. There were no hidden or squashed faces, the face in question is planar (scale y 0 and apply scale changed nothing) and yet it still baked as if it weren't. Odd for sure, but at least there's the solution.

Thanks again!

Comment: It's because it shoots rays in the direction of per-sample normals from the low poly, which in the case of a smooth shaded mesh are not the same as the face normals, but interpolated between vertex normals.